# How to get image form another model in django

Tags: html, django, django-models

I want to get image form **Image** model for my **Product** model and show it cart template

This is my Code:

ecommerce/models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    excerpt = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    author = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    featured_image = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Image(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

cart/views.py

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                 quantity=cd['quantity'],
                 update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')    

def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'],
                                                                   'update': True})
    return render(request, 'cart_detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

cart/templates/cart.html

```
<tbody>
        {% for item in cart %}
            {% with product=item.product %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {% for product in products %} 
                        <img src="{{ product.first_image.src }}" alt="" width="auto" height="340"/>
                    {% endfor %}
                </td>
                <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
                .
                .
                .
            </tr>
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

i have read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432785/how-to-get-image-connected-by-foreign-key-via-template-in-django)

but it is no use to me, please help me, I am newby to this

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use reverse lookup `image_set`. To get first image do `product.image_set.first.image.url`:

```
<img src="{{ product.image_set.first.image.url }}" alt="" width="auto" height="340"/>
```

to get all images iterate over `image_set`:

```
{% for image in product.image_set.all %} 
    <img src="{{ image.src }}" alt="" width="auto" height="340"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Note you should remove this part:

```
{% for product in products %} 
{% endfor %}
```

since you dont pass `products` variable into template context.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but it didn't work for me, no error, but no change