# how to get image connected by a foreign key django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, backend

i want to get a image from the image model in the template

The Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    Product_Type=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    Product_Name=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    Product_Size=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Product_Price=models.FloatField()

    def first_image(self):
        #code to determeni image
        return self.images.first()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Product_Name

class Product_Image(models.Model):
    Product_name=models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="images", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Product_Image=models.ImageField( upload_to="images/", height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None)
     
    def __img__(self):
        return self.Product_Image
```

The view

```
def index(request):
    new_products = Product.objects.all()
    # Retrieve the desired image associated with the product
    context = {'new_products': new_products}
   
    return render(request, "Genesis/home.html", context)
```

l want to get image connected to that product, through my reading, studies and research have not fixed anything and no error has popped out

some of my research include a youtube video [fetching image in django](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXG11HcJtOw&pp=ygUwaG93IHRvIGdldCBhbiBpbWFnZSB0aHJvdWdoIGEgZm9yZWlnbiBrZXkgZGphbmdv)

and also [How to get image connected by foreign key via template in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056844/django-how-to-get-data-connected-by-foreignkey-via-template)

but no success

```
{%if new_products %}
     {%for product in new_products%}
          <div class="col mb-5">
              <div class="card h-100">
                   <!-- Product image-->
                            
             <img src="{{ Product_name.first_image.images.url }}" alt="Product Image">
                 <!-- Product details-->
                 <div class="card-body p-4">
                      <div class="text-center">
                           <!-- Product name-->
                             <h5 class="fw-bolder">{{product.Product_Type}}</h5>
                                 <!-- Product price-->
                              $40.00 - $80.00
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to get image url from Product_name that is a field of product and you cant use it like that. another problem is, you are trying to access first_image and then images.url. However, the first_image method already returns the image instance, so you can directly access its Product_Image attribute. try this:

```
                <img src="{{ product.first_image.Product_Image.url }}" alt="Product Image">
```